# get child level in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have table has id and perent as the following:

```
id   parent
12      0
21      12
34      12
47      21
57      21
66      21
77      34
88      47
```

I want to write query take id and return which level this id:

for example

```
1 => level 1
2 and 3 => level 2
4 => level 3
... and so on.
```

what i tried:

```
SELECT cc1.id, count(cc1.id) c FROM community_comments cc1
inner join community_comments cc2 on cc1.id = cc2.parent 
AND cc1.parent = 324 group by cc1.parent
```

this return how many level under 324 level and this not what i want

Comment: why it is tagged with mysqli?

Comment: i am using mysqli engine

Comment: Consider switching to a nested set model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am solving it using PHP code

```
function get_comment_level($comment_id){

        $query = "select parent from community_comments where id = $comment_id";

        $result = $this->conn->db_query($query);

        $level = 1;
        $parent = 0;

        while ($row = $this->conn->db_fetch_object($result)){
            $parent = $row->parent;
        }

        if ($parent != 0) {
            $level = $this->get_comment_level($parent);
            $level++;
        }

        return $level;
    }
```